# Margin error in Stack App add Favorite/Ignored tag buttons

Tags: bug, design, stackapps

*That is **not a duplicate** of the related question*. That question is about `stackoverflow` and `meta.stackoverflow` while my question is about `Stack Apps`. So if this question is kept closed, then the other question will end up as *cuold not repruduced* since that bug is not reproducable in other stack exchange sites (I check some other Stack Exchange sites including beta sites and some meta sites.)

Error occurs on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)

When I click to add Favorite or ignored tag, `Add` button is cropped from the right side.

Favorite Tag Bug:

> [image]

Ignored Tag Bug:

> [image]

Occured in `Firefox 26.0` on `Linux Mint`.

Comment: Firefox only think it's already reported, let me search... found.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  did you see that your dup has a dup that is closed as not longer reproducible? Shouldn't the original dup be reopened?

Comment: @rene yes, and I also voted to reopen the dupe as its dupe was closed.

Comment: OK, I don't have priveleges to vote for reopen but I support that vote if it matters....

Comment: I guess this is not a duplicate, since SO, meta.SO and some other sites on the network (I tired a few of them, including some beta sites). The buttons look good. Only occurs in `Stack Apps`

Comment: @ShadowWizard retract your re-open vote on that question because it defines the problem as SO and meta.SO specific. But that error occurs only on Stack Apps.

Comment: @FallenAngel we can't retract reopen votes, only close votes. Should have checked indeed on Stack Overflow, but anyway it's still Firefox only and should be addressed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard then can you retract your close vote on this question?

Comment: Voted to reopen, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, still active...